# Clojure overloaded method resolution for Longs

Tags: types, clojure

This behavior makes no sense to me:

```
user=> (type 1)
java.lang.Long
user=> (type (cast Long 1))
java.lang.Long
user=> (type 1)
java.lang.Long
user=> (type (Long. 1))
java.lang.Long
user=> (type (cast Long 1))
java.lang.Long
user=> (BigDecimal. 1)
1M
user=> (BigDecimal. (Long. 1))
CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: More than one matching method found: java.math.BigDecimal, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:22) 
user=> (BigDecimal. (cast Long 1))
1M
```

Why does the `(BigDecimal. (Long. 1))` case fail to find an unambiguous matching method signature while the other two expressions—which have exactly the same argument type—succeed?

---

## *Update:*

What I find even *more* strange about this behavior is that it seems particular to the `Long` type:

```
user=> (BigDecimal. (Long. 1))
CompilerException java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: More than one matching method found: java.math.BigDecimal, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1) 
user=> (BigDecimal. (Integer. 1))
1M
```

Comment: Interestingly, forced coercion works: `(BigDecimal. (long (Long. 1)))`

Comment: Notice that it doesn't fail to find a matching method signature. It finds more than one, so the call is ambiguous... or so it claims. Very interesting indeed.

Comment: @Tom - When I said _fail to find a match_ I meant _fail to find an **unambiguous** match_. I've updated the question—thanks!.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [this discussion on the Clojure discussion group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/clojure/7-hARL5c1lI/ntnnOweEGfUJ) it seems you have encountered a design decision made by Rich Hickey. Specifically, because BigDecimal does not have a constructor of the signature `BigDecimal(Long long)` **(Edit:** and therefore leaves the compiler having to choose between the `int` and `long` constructors - see comments below for discussion on why using `Integer` works), the compiler will not attempt to "guess" which constructor you will meant, and explicitly fails.

> The bottom line is specific type requirements on the Java side require explicit boxing on order to have correct and non-brittle code. - Rich Hickey

Note that literals are parsed as primitives, not "boxed" types, per [this documentation](http://dev.clojure.org/display/doc/Documentation+for+1.3+Numerics):

> In contrast to previous versions of Clojure, numeric literals are parsed as primitive longs or doubles.

To understand why the other operations work, you have to dig into Clojure source, specifically `Compiler.java` and its inner class [`NumberExpr`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.4.0/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java#L1728).  That is the where your literal gets auto-boxed to a `Long` and the compiler has no problem in turn calling `Object.getClass()` (which both `type` and `class` do).

In the [`Compiler.getMatchingParams()`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.4.0/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Compiler.java#L2309), the Clojure compiler attempts to resolve which constructor of `BigDecimal` to use.  However, you have explicitly specified that your parameter has the type `Long` - there is no constructor for BigDecimal that takes that type.

Maybe this isn't "common sense," but Rich Hickey made the decision that you need to be precise about the type of your parameters and that they have to match the type of the Java class. The compiler is refusing to guess your intent.

Note the following:

```
user=> (new BigDecimal 1M)
Reflection warning, NO_SOURCE_PATH:33 - call to java.math.BigDecimal ctor can't be resolved.
IllegalArgumentException No matching ctor found for class java.math.BigDecimal  clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeConstructor (Reflector.java:183)
```

Also note that this Java code is valid and resolves to the `int` constructor for BigDecimal:

```
    byte b = 1;
    new BigDecimal(new Byte(b));
```

But this code also fails (even though it "should" use the `int` constructor):

```
user=> (BigDecimal. (Byte. (byte 1)))
Reflection warning, NO_SOURCE_PATH:37 - call to java.math.BigDecimal ctor can't be resolved.
IllegalArgumentException No matching ctor found for class java.math.BigDecimal  clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeConstructor (Reflector.java:183)
```

tl;dr: Clojure supports Java *interop* but that does not mean it has to follow the promotion rules of Java Language Specification.

**What about `cast`?**

A comment below asks about `(cast)`. In that case you are explicitly telling the Clojure compiler to delegate type resolution to the JVM. Note the following (nonsensical) code that compiles, yet fails at runtime:

```
user=> (set! *warn-on-reflection* true)
true
user=> (defn make-big-dec [obj] (BigDecimal. (cast Math obj)))
Reflection warning, NO_SOURCE_PATH:7 - call to java.math.BigDecimal ctor can't be resolved.
#'user/make-big-dec
user=> (make-big-dec 1)
ClassCastException   java.lang.Class.cast (Class.java:2990)
```

**Epilogue II**

There has been quite a bit of discussion on this topic in the Clojure community. Please check out these detailed threads:

[Enhanced Primitive Support](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/clojure/yMhQWVyRzBE) (Rich Hickey)

[Clojure 1.3 treatment of integers and longs](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/clojure/7-hARL5c1lI/hJyJRbRV70oJ) (Nathan Marz)

Comment: This is interesting but it doesn't explain why `(BigDecimal. (Long. 1))` fails but `(BigDecimal. (cast Long 1))` works. If you run `(type (Long. 1))` and `(type (cast Long 1))` they both report the type as `java.lang.Long`. Why does one work but not the other?

Comment: Good question. `(cast)` is a runtime operation. Clojure doesn't know what the returned type of the object is.  It's delegating to Java reflection (see `Object.cast()`).  Therefore, compilation works, but with the reflection warning "call to java.math.BigDecimal ctor can't be resolved." This is just like "hard-casting" in Java code. Now you've forced the code to succeed compilation, but who knows what will happen at runtime?

Comment: This is an interesting answer, but it doesn't explain why Clojure chokes on applying the `BigDecimal` constructor to a `Long` but not an `Integer`. If it were really just a problem with boxing/unboxing then I'd expect it to fail on the boxed `Integer` type as well. I've updated my question with this example.

Comment: Please have a look at `Reflector.java` method [`paramArgTypeMatch()`](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.4.0/src/jvm/clojure/lang/Reflector.java#L449). They have decided that your `Long` could either match the constructor for `int` or `long`, but your `Integer` can only match the constructor for `int`.  Remember that the problem is that Clojure found *two* possible constructors. Not the case when you specify `Integer`. You may want to open a new question (here or on the mailing list) asking about Clojure's position on types and why an `int` cannot be a `long`.

Answer (score 1):

BigDecimal does not have a constructor for Long,

BigDecimal(BigInteger val)

```
core> (BigDecimal. (BigInteger/ONE))
1M
```

BigDecimal(BigInteger unscaledVal, int scale)

```
core> (BigDecimal. BigInteger/ONE 1)
0.1M
```

BigDecimal(double val)

```
core> (BigDecimal. (double 1))
1M
core> (BigDecimal. (float 1))
1M
(BigDecimal. Double/MIN_VALUE)
```

BigDecimal(String val)

```
core> (BigDecimal. "1")
1M
```

It's unclear which of these `(Long. 1)` matches. the `clojure.core.bigdec` function works on this input by passing it's input to `BigDec/valueOf` to create the BigDecimal

```
core>  (bigdec (Long. 1))
1M
```

uses this call:

```
(BigDecimal/valueOf (long x))
```