# Clojure java interop - calling overloaded (static) methods

Tags: java, clojure, interop

Although I do somewhat understand the reasons behind it, I find LWJGL's splitting of OpenGL methods and values across numerous classes rather annoying. Since I prefer dealing with functions anyway, I'm currently writing a Clojure module that exposes the OpenGL 3.3 core functions and constants in a single namespace.

Now the problem is, some OpenGL functions have overloads in LWJGL like for instance `glBindAttribLocation` has one for `ByteBuffer` and one for `CharSequence`. Now I'm saying 'problem' in the broadest sense because I'm not sure yet whether this really is one.

Can I for instance just write

```
(defn glBindAttribLocation [program index name]
  (GL20/glBindAttribLocation program index name))
```

and trust that Clojure will figure out which overload to call, or do I have to do this manually with some typehint-uglyness?

On the same note, many of LWJGL's functions take `float`s or `int`s - but I hear Clojure itself only uses `long` and `double` (of the primitives that is). Does that mean that everytime I call one of these functions, whatever I have gets converted to an `Integer` (`Float`) and then from there to an `int` (`float`) whenever I call one of these functions?

Comment: The conversion is probably directly `long->int` and `float->double`, if that is any consolation :) Calling overloaded functions really is a drag and there is no help about it.

Answer (score 1):

I've had weird problems with `long->int` conversion, but only when there is an overloaded signature for both `int` and `long`, creating ambiguities. If there are only methods for `int` and `float` (which, from looking at the documentation seems to be the case) then you should be fine. Clojure will automatically do the long->int and double->float conversions:

```
user=> (Float/isInfinite 5.0) ; Takes a float
false
user=> (Integer/numberOfTrailingZeros 4) ; Takes an int
2
```

As for `GL20/glBindAttribLocation`, the only times I've had to cast for overloaded methods are 1) if they have both an `int` and `long` version or 2) if I'm passing `nil` as a parameter for an object, making it impossible to guess which method I wanted. Since the first two arguments must be `int`s, unless you can pass `nil` for the `name` parameter then you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will likely need to coerce data to type proper type if there are multiple candidate methods for an invocation due to overloading.  The good news is that the Clojure compiler will likely raise an error, rather than give you surprising behavior.

See: [Clojure overloaded method resolution for Longs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586881/clojure-overloaded-method-resolution-for-longs)

Comment: That seems to be a problem particular to `Long`s. The LWJGL library only uses `int` and `float`, the overloads are things like `ByteBuffer` vs `CharSequence` vs `CharSequence[]`

Comment: Not quite. You can still get a warning such as `Reflection warning, call to <class method-or-ctor> can't be resolved.` when the compile-time type is ambiguous.