# How does integer type casting works in java interop?

Tags: casting, clojure, clojure-java-interop

```
public class Hello {
  public static void test(int i) {
    System.out.println("int");
  }

  public static void test(long l) {
    System.out.println("long");
  }
}


user=> (def foo 1)
#'user/foo

user=> (type foo)
java.lang.Long

user=> (Hello/test 1)
long
nil

user=> (Hello/test foo)
int
nil

user=> (Integer. 1)
1

user=> (Integer. foo)
1

user=> (Short. 1)
IllegalArgumentException No matching ctor found for class java.lang.Short  clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeConstructor (Reflector.java:183)
```

I couldn't figure out the rules.

Answer (score 1):

In short, Clojure does not have the same overloading behavior as Java.  It is a different language (that runs on the JVM) with its own set of rules.  So if you define a method `test(short s)` it will work because you have a specific matching method signature, but the Clojure compiler won't otherwise do a widening conversion to the "closest" method.

For a more complete discussion with links, see my answer to this question:
[Clojure overloaded method resolution for Longs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586881/clojure-overloaded-method-resolution-for-longs/12589410#12589410)

Comment: Why `(Hello/test foo)` selects the int overload? Why `(Short. 1)` fails while `(Integer. 1)` succeeds? No official documentation for all the rules? Should I read the source code of the compiler?

Comment: Read this post by Rich Hickey, linked from my other answer: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/clojure/7-hARL5c1lI/ntnnOweEGfUJ

Comment: Regarding documentation: http://dev.clojure.org/display/doc/Documentation+for+1.3+Numerics - note that behavior might depend on your Clojure version.